# Nginx forwarding by server name

Tags: linux, dns, port-forwarding, nginx

I have several dockerized services, serving http (and https). The internal http port (80) is mapped at the docker level to a different port, so that is is reachable on the host. And this is working fine:

```
curl localhost:1234
```

Brings me to my http service in the container.

Now I would like this to be reachable via a dns, without having to specify the port (I want to shield the clients from this port mapping). I would like to use nginx to forward requests to `http://myserver1` -> `http://localhost:1234`.

Can nginx be configured in that way? Can it be configured for multiple forwarding, as follows:

```
http://myserver1  --> http://localhost:1234
http://myserver2  --> http://localhost:1235
...
```

Comment: This could be done (for example) using a reverse proxy setup which is possible with Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.

the server_name option is used to find a best match between different sites hosted on the same nginx server like

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name myserver1;
```

and another one like

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name myserver2;
```

This way they can run both on port 80 and match depending on if they are called by http://myserver1 or http://myserver2.

Now how to connect to your services? You can define upstream service providers like

```
#place this outside of the 'server{' block
upstream server1 {
  server localhost:1234;
}
```

and then redirect to it via

```
# place this inside the 'server{' block
location / {
  proxy_pass http://server1;
}
```